Errors when installing google-colab
While installing google-colab there seems to be an issue. I tried many things but it seem to be persistent, can anyone tell me what's the issue here and how to resolve it?
\`PS C:\\Users\\Shreyas\> pip install google-colab

Collecting google-colab

Downloading google-colab-1.0.0.tar.gz (72 kB)

Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done

Collecting google-auth\~=1.4.0 (from google-colab)

Downloading google_auth-1.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)

Collecting ipykernel\~=4.6.0 (from google-colab)

Downloading ipykernel-4.6.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (981 bytes)

Collecting ipython\~=5.5.0 (from google-colab)

Downloading ipython-5.5.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.3 kB)

Requirement already satisfied: notebook\~=5.2.0 in c:\\users\\shreyas\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python311\\lib\\site-packages (from google-colab) (5.2.2)

Collecting six\~=1.12.0 (from google-colab)

Downloading six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.9 kB)

Collecting pandas\~=0.24.0 (from google-colab)

Downloading pandas-0.24.2.tar.gz (11.8 MB)

11.8/11.8 MB 874.7 kB/s eta 0:00:00

Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error

error: subprocess-exited-with-error

python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.

exit code: 1

\[175 lines of output\]

C:\\Users\\Shreyas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-d4d054p6\\pandas_71e68076abd34e78aef730b7a906beef\\setup.py:12: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html

import pkg_resources

C:\\Users\\Shreyas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-d4d054p6\\pandas_71e68076abd34e78aef730b7a906beef\\setup.py:50: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.

\_CYTHON_INSTALLED = ver \>= LooseVersion(min_cython_ver)

warning: pandas\\\_libs\\parsers.pyx:1764:34: Casting a GIL-requiring function into a nogil function circumvents GIL validation

warning: pandas\\\_libs\\tslibs\\period.pyx:158:19: Casting a GIL-requiring function into a nogil function circumvents GIL validation

warning: pandas\\\_libs\\tslibs\\period.pyx:160:19: Casting a GIL-requiring function into a nogil function circumvents GIL validation

warning: pandas\\\_libs\\tslibs\\period.pyx:162:19: Casting a GIL-requiring function into a nogil

warning: pandas\\\_libs\\tslib.pyx:720:49: Buffer unpacking not optimized away.

warning: pandas\\\_libs\\tslib.pyx:720:49: Buffer unpacking not optimized away.

Compiling pandas\\\_libs/algos.pyx because it depends on C:\\Users\\Shreyas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\Cython\\Includes\\libc\\string.pxd.

Compiling pandas\\\_libs/groupby.pyx because it depends on C:\\Users\\Shreyas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\Cython\\Includes\\libc\\string.pxd.

1/36\] Cythonizing pandas\\\_libs/algos.pyx

2/36\] Cythonizing pandas\\\_libs/parsers.pyx

3/36\] Cythonizing pandas\\\_libs/skiplist.pyx

4/36\] Cythonizing pandas\\\_libs/tslibs/period.pyx

5/36\] Cythonizing pandas\\\_libs/window.pyx

6/36\] Cythonizing pandas\\io/msgpack/\_unpacker.pyx

7/36\] Cythonizing pandas\\\_libs/groupby.pyx

8/36\] Cythonizing pandas\\\_libs/hashing.pyx

9/36\] Cythonizing pandas\\\_libs/hashtable.pyx

\[10/36\] Cythonizing pandas\\\_libs/index.pyx

\[11/36\] Cythonizing pandas\\\_libs/internals.pyx

\[12/36\] Cythonizing pandas\\\_libs/interval.pyx

\[13/36\] Cythonizing pandas\\\_libs/join.pyx

\[14/36\] Cythonizing pandas\\\_libs/lib.pyx

\[15/36\] Cythonizing pandas\\\_libs/missing.pyx

\[16/36\] Cythonizing pandas\\\_libs/ops.pyx

\[17/36\] Cythonizing pandas\\\_libs/properties.pyx

\[18/36\] Cythonizing pandas\\\_libs/reduction.pyx

\[19/36\] Cythonizing pandas\\\_libs/reshape.pyx

\[20/36\] Cythonizing pandas\\\_libs/sparse.pyx

\[21/36\] Cythonizing pandas\\\_libs/tslib.pyx

\[22/36\] Cythonizing pandas\\\_libs/tslibs/ccalendar.pyx

\[23/36\] Cythonizing pandas\\\_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyx

\[24/36\] Cythonizing pandas\\\_libs/tslibs/fields.pyx

\[25/36\] Cythonizing pandas\\\_libs/tslibs/frequencies.pyx

\[26/36\] Cythonizing pandas\\\_libs/tslibs/nattype.pyx

\[27/36\] Cythonizing pandas\\\_libs/tslibs/np_datetime.pyx

\[28/36\] Cythonizing pandas\\\_libs/tslibs/offsets.pyx

\[29/36\] Cythonizing pandas\\\_libs/tslibs/parsing.pyx

\[30/36\] Cythonizing pandas\\\_libs/tslibs/resolution.pyx

\[31/36\] Cythonizing pandas\\\_libs/tslibs/strptime.pyx

\[32/36\] Cythonizing pandas\\\_libs/tslibs/timedeltas.pyx

\[33/36\] Cythonizing pandas\\\_libs/tslibs/timestamps.pyx

\[34/36\] Cythonizing pandas\\\_libs/tslibs/timezones.pyx

\[35/36\] Cythonizing pandas\\\_libs/writers.pyx

\[36/36\] Cythonizing pandas\\io/msgpack/\_packer.pyx

C:\\Users\\Shreyas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\setuptools\\\__init_\_.py:85: \_DeprecatedInstaller: setuptools.installer and fetch_build_eggs are deprecated.

!!

\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*

Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.

If you are using pip, you can try \`pip install --use-pep517\`.

\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*

!!

dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)

error in pandas setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Expected end or semicolon (after version specifier)

pytz \>= 2011k

\\\>                \~\~\~\~\~\~\~^

\[end of output\]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

error: metadata-generation-failed

Encountered error while generating package metadata.

See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.

hint: See above for details.


Try using  pip install --use-pep517 google-colab.

It is right in the error:
********************************************************************************

Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.

If you are using pip, you can try `pip install --use-pep517`.

********************************************************************************


Have you tried?
